# trying to add a sticky veteran owned business badge to website

Tags: html, css, icons, sticky, badge

I've done a bit of research and I can only seem to find adding side bars and buttons which I'm not interested in adding. I have a png of the badge id like to add and I would like it to be sticky in the bottom right corner or the screen. any help would be much appreciated! thanks ahead of time.

Comment: `position: fixed; bottom: 0;  right: 0;`? What have you tried? where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: this is what I have now. and It doesnt show an image.                                                                 img.sticky {
    position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
  } <img class="sticky" src="img/owner" alt="Avatar">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to simply use `position: fixed` to that badge image. It will move the image out of flow and position it fixed inside the viewport. Use `bottom` + `right`-proeprty to align it in the bottom right corner:

```css
.badge {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}

/* for demonstration purpose only */
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 500vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, yellow, blue);
}
```

```html
<img class="badge" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50.jpg">
```

Comment: ill give that a try and let you know how it goes thanks for replying so quickly.